# can I play a sound while the iPhone is sleeping?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, media, avaudioplayer

How can I play a custom, looping sound (from my app, while my app is open) while the iPhone is sleeping?

I'm using this code to play a audio file:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_name" ofType:@"wav"];
NSData *sampleData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
NSError *audioError = nil;

// Set up the audio player
testAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sampleData error:&audioError];
[sampleData release];

if(audioError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"An audio error occurred: \"%@\"", audioError);
}
else {
    [testAudioPlayer setNumberOfLoops: -1];
    [testAudioPlayer play];
}
```

But it doesn't play if the iPhone is sleeping.

Pandora has this ability, along with other similar apps.

Comment: do you mean a continous sound or rather a notification?

Comment: @Axel : I mean a custom "mp3" looping sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are playing a sound when the phone goes to sleep, you will continue to run in the background as Pandora and others do.

If you are not playing a sound when the user puts the device to sleep, you will be suspended.

There's a reference in this answer to the apple documentation for this.
[Play sound with screen turned off / don't let iPhone go to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267466/ios-play-sound-with-screen-turned-off-dont-let-iphone-go-to-sleep)

Answer (score 0):

Try registering for a local notification.